# What is the maximum number of columns allowed in a table?

Tags: oracle, datatable

What is the maximum number of columns allowed in an **Oracle** table, in the following versions?

- Oracle 8i
- Oracle 9i
- Oracle 10g
- Oracle 11g
- Oracle 12c

Comment: This should be covered in the respective documentation under the "limits" (or equivalent) section: -1 because this information should be gleaned from the official references.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A limit of 1,000 columns per table applies for versions [8i](http://www.mbjconsulting.com/oracle_links/Oracle_8i_and_9i_Limitations.html), [9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch44.htm), [10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm), [11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm), [12c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76), [18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/logical-database-limits.html) and [19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html).

Prior to that, [Oracle 7](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SRF73/ch5.htm) had a 254 column limit.

Answer (score 5):

for Oracle 11g :

1000 Columns per table

32 columns per index

Logical Database Limits:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032

Answer (score 3):

**For version [11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/limits003.htm#REFRN0043),[10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm#i288032),[9i](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch44.htm) and [8i](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76961/ch44.htm) column size:-**

Per table:1000 columns maximum

Per index (or clustered index):32 columns maximum

Per bitmapped index:30 columns maximum